# Bluetooth Issues Sending AVRCP Volume Changes Using D-Bus (qdbus) Send With org.bluez.MediaTransport1

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, dbus

I am working on emulating a Bluetooth headphone for automated testing using a raspberry pi as my headphone. Part of the challenge I was facing initially was to send AVRCP commands from the PI to the source device. I was delighted to find dbus and its capabilities in sending pause, play, next, and all the other commands. I wound up hitting a brick wall when it came to volume changes though. As it turns out the stock PulseAudio 9.0 binary doesn’t support absolute volume. After finding this patch - https://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/76558/ - I was able to set my volume on the source device (in my case an iPhone). After getting this fixed I went about trying to figure out how to send volume change commands from the PI to the source device. There is a property called Volume in org.bluez.MediaTransport1 that I can read but setting it has been a nightmare. I am always getting the following problems.

**Command**

> qdbus --system org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/fdX
>   org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.bluez.MediaTransport1 Volume
>   127

**Response**

> Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidSignature Invalid signature
>   for ‘Volume’

I have tried scouring the internet to come up with various payloads and nothing has worked. I’ve hit a brick wall in finding the proper way to set the volume. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: were you successful ?

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but let it be just in case:

```
dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply=literal --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/fdX org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:org.bluez.MediaTransport1 string:Volume variant:uint16:127
```